# mysql count from joins using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, concatenation

i'm trying to build a chat application, in which i have these four tables

1. `chat` --id,group_id,body,time_posted[timestamp]
2. `chat_groups`  --establish id,name for a group
3. `users_groups`  --link users to a group, also define if user stared this group FIELDS::user_id,group_id,stared[bool]
4. `wall_visit` --user_id,group_id,last_visit[timestamp]

the idea is every users join a group, and they post to it in chat.
chat_groups table is just for defining the room, while users_groups is for setting access of members to this group.

wall_visit table is a table that store specific user last time accessed specific group (since its many to many u know..)

now what im trying to establish is to get in one query,

1. the `chat_groups` the user in relation with
2. the count of messages posted to this group since user last login (from settings)
3. the count of members in this group
4. the group name

:)
i have been trying to hours now :( best i could come up with

```
SELECT w.last_visit,access.stared,cg.user_id,u.fullname as username,cg.name as group_name ,cgu.count_members,c.count_msgs,c.time_posted
            FROM `chat_groups`cg
            inner join chat_groups_users access on (access.group_id = cg.id and access.user_id = ?)
            left outer join users u on u.id = cg.user_id
            left join wall_visit w on w.group_id = cg.id
            left  join (select count(*) as count_members,group_id from group_users group by group_id) cgu on cgu.group_id = cg.id
            left join (SELECT count(wv.id) as count_msgs,c.group_id,c.time_posted FROM chats c
left outer join `wall_visit` wv on (wv.group_id is not null and c.group_id = wv.group_id and c.time_posted > wv.last_visit)
group by c.group_id) c on c.group_id = cg.id
            where cg.user_id = 1
```

this query is working ..ehh, **my main problem is with the count of the messages in the group since last_visit.**

1. what is the best methode to get message_count to work :( ??
2. can this query be optimized more?

Thanks SO community :)

My 2nd attempt

```
SELECT w.last_visit,access.stared,cg.user_id,u.fullname as username,cg.with_id,uu.fullname as with_name,cg.name as group_name ,cgu.count_members,c.count_msgs,c.time_posted
            FROM `chat_groups`cg
            inner join chat_groups_users access on (access.group_id = cg.id and access.user_id = 1)
            left outer join users u on u.id = cg.user_id
            left join wall_visit w on w.chat_id = cg.id
            left outer join users uu on uu.id = cg.with_id
            left  join (select count(*) as count_members,group_id from chat_groups_users group by group_id) cgu on cgu.group_id = cg.id
            left join (
            SELECT group_id,count(c.id) as count_msgs,time_posted FROM `chats` c inner join wall_Visit wv on wv.chat_id = c.group_id where c.id > wv.last_visit group by c.group_id
            ) c on c.group_id = cg.id
            where cg.user_id = 1
```

Comment: can you pass your tables structure to http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: and insert some data in them :)

Comment: just do it. i will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should fix you count message problem

```
SELECT 

    `cg`.`user_id`, `cg`.`with_id`, `cg`.`name` AS `group_name`,
    `access`.`stared`,
    `u`.`fullname` AS `username`,
    `w`.`last_visit`,    
    `uu`.`fullname` AS `with_name`, 
    `cgu`.`count_members`, 
    `c`.`count_msgs`, `c`.`time_posted`

FROM `chat_groups` AS `cg`
INNER JOIN `chat_groups_users` AS `access` 
            ON (`access`.`group_id` = `cg`.`id` AND `access`.`user_id` = `cg`.`user_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `u` 
            ON (`u`.`id` = `cg`.`user_id`)
LEFT JOIN `wall_visit` AS `w` 
            ON (`w`.`chat_id` = `cg`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `uu` 
            ON (`uu`.`id` = `cg`.`with_id`)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count_members`, `group_id` 
    FROM `chat_groups_users` 
    GROUP BY 
        `group_id`
) AS `cgu` 
            ON (`cgu`.`group_id` = `cg`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(`c`.`id`) AS `count_msgs`, `c`.`time_posted` 
    FROM `chats` AS `c` 
    INNER JOIN `wall_visit` AS `wv` 
            ON (`wv`.`chat_id` = `c`.`group_id`) 
    WHERE 
        `c`.`time_posted` > `wv`.`last_visit` 
    GROUP BY 
        `c`.`group_id`
) AS `c` 
            ON (`c`.`group_id` = `cg`.`id`)
WHERE `cg`.`user_id` = 1
```

otherwise u have to setup a fiddle